# Using option types instead of exceptions for a recursive descent parser?

Tags: parsing, exception, ocaml, recursive-descent

I'm writing a simple recursive descent parser in OCaml. Typically (as far as I can tell from the tutorials online and in books), exceptions are used to indicate parse failures, for example:

```
match tok with
   TokPlus -> ...
 | _ -> raise SyntaxError
```

However, I'm thinking of using the option type instead, i.e.:

```
match tok with
   TokPlus -> Some(...)
 | _ -> None
```

The main reason I want to do this is that using option types allows me to optimize some of my combinators to be tail-recursive.

Are there any shortcomings with using options instead of exceptions? Will this decision bite me in the foot as I start parsing more complex structures?

Comment: In the end, I returned to using exceptions, and used options to optimize the few cases where there would be deeply nested recursions (mainly the repeat combinators). There turned out to be several places where I would have had to manually match the options and propagate errors; in the end exceptions made a lot more sense. So if anybody else is thinking about this, just keep with using exceptions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe exceptions optimize the common case - the code path for successful parse is simpler. Usually when parsing it is all or nothing - either everything parses ok and you return the final result or something breaks - and you don't care where it breaks because you are not going to handle it anyway, except to print meaningful message, but one can skip that step too :) So looks like a perfect match for exceptions.

Comment: Agreed; I agonized over not using exceptions for quite a while, because it really is the natural way of writing such code. I wonder if I'm committing the sin of premature optimization.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you'll likely have to add (a lot of) dummy rules to propagate the error back to the root production of the grammar.

The point of exceptions is you don't have to add exception handlers to each routine; you get implicit propagation.

Is there a specific reason you want optimized tail recursion?  Most parsers don't actually produce very deep call stacks (a few hundred levels for really complex stuff).  And I doubt the time savings is significant compared to all the other work being done by the non-parser part.

Comment: Hmm... I was worried about the call stack getting too deep, although I guess I'm really not sure how nested the calls will be, really; the main combinator that I was trying to optimize was _repeat_, which recurses once for each repeated element.  
  
I'm aware that there is more work to be done when using options instead, but so far I've managed to hide most of the complexity within the combinators, so my top-level rules still appear pretty clean.

Comment: My worst-ever parse call stack came from parsing a C array initializer data list.  The C array being initialized represented a ROM.  The initializer list contained bytes in hex to fill the ROM; there were about a million entries, so the stack got to be a million entries deep.    Parsed fine on a modern x86.

Comment: It's unlikely your C compiler was using a recursive descent parser.  Probably it was using a yacc parser, in fact (table-driven LALR).  Also, a C array initializer isn't built from deeply nested components.  Just some observations.

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about recursive descent parsing is that you can write the code any way you like (within reason).  I don't see a problem writing tail recursively with or without exceptions, unless you would imagine catching exceptions in all your intermediate functions.  More likely you'd have one (or a few) exception handlers near the top of your grammar, in which case all the code below could easily be tail recursive.

So, I agree with ygrek that the exception style is quite natural for parsing, and I don't think using exceptions necessarily precludes tail recursive style.

Comment: There are certain cases where you need to catch the exception within the function, and as a result the code isn't tail recursive because the recursive call is within the context of a try/catch. In particular my repeat combinator needs to catch the parse failure (in order to know it has reached the end of the repeated elements). While there's a workaround to make it tail recursive, it's not very elegant.

Comment: Well, this sounds like you're using exceptions to control a correct parse.  If your language is reasonable, you should be able to control the parse using token lookahead and reserve exceptions for the error cases.  You might try parameterizing your repeat combinator by the "follow" set.  This is what you'd be doing (essentially) if you wrote without generalized combinators.  I think this is still pretty elegant (personal opinion).